# spring mvc request method 404 error

Tags: spring-mvc, request-mapping

```
@Controller("/UserAction")
@RequestMapping("/greet.json")
public class UserAction extends BaseAction {

@RequestMapping(value = "/hello", method = RequestMethod.GET)

public void hello(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) {

    System.out.println("a");
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/word", method = RequestMethod.GET)

public void word(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) {


    System.out.println("123123@@@");
}
```

}

when I look http://localhost:8080/ProjectName/greet.json/hello
and http://localhost:8080/ProjectName/greet.json/word
can't excute the syso method

Mapped "{[/greet.json],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public void cn.elfsoft.controller.UserAction.hello(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
08:33:38,488 INFO  [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory] (org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry:433) - Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@4eed49c9: defining beans [org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor,AnswerAction,FileResourceAction,SendMessageAction,SubjectAction,userAction,videoAction,baseDAO,FileResource,QuestionDao,SubjectDao,videoDao,FileResourceService,QuestionService,SubjectService,UserService,videoService,org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.MappedInterceptor#0,org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator,cn.elfsoft.log.LogAdvice#0,dataSource,org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor#0,sessionFactory,jdbcTemplate,txManager,org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0,org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor#0,org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor,businessService,org.springframework.aop.support.DefaultBeanFactoryPointcutAdvisor#0,txAdvice,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor$ImportAwareBeanPostProcessor#0]; root of factory hierarchy
08:33:38,490 ERROR [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] (org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet:460) - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping#0' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/web-config.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous mapping found. Cannot map 'userAction' bean method 
public void cn.elfsoft.controller.UserAction.word(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
to {[/greet.json],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}: There is already 'userAction' bean method
public void cn.elfsoft.controller.UserAction.hello(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse) mapped.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have 2 annotations that confuse your operation, try to use only this:

```
@Controller
public class UserAction extends BaseAction {

@RequestMapping(value = "/greet.json/hello", method = RequestMethod.GET)

public void hello(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) {

    System.out.println("a");
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/greet.json/word", method = RequestMethod.GET)

public void word(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) {


     System.out.println("123123@@@");
}
```

And if you want to use a common path to your controller add to 
    @Controller("/commonPath")

And later on each method with the

```
@RequestMapping("/specificEndPoint")
```